# Oracle REGEXP_LIKE find vertical tab 0xb character

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-like

Trying to find a vertical tab character in a CLOB field.  Using regexp_like which doesn't support entry of hex characters.
so this is not valid
and REGEXP_LIKE(,'[\xB]','i')
Posix entries don't seem to help as :cntl: includes items like carriage return/new line which is valid in my scenario.

Comment: The regular expression can simply be `chr(9)` (not in quotes). What's the 'i' at the end in your attempt though? That's for case insensitive search; that doesn't apply to control characters.

Comment: I think you mean `chr(11)`

Comment: Whatever the correct ASCII code is; I expect the OP will be able to find that out on his own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two standard ways of specifying non-printing characters in Oracle - `chr()` for the 8-bit codepages and `unistr()` for UTF-16. Here's an example that shows both of them (vertical tab is decimal 11 for 8-bit and \000B for UTF-16).

```
with test as (select to_clob(unistr('\000B')) as str from dual)
select 'Found' from test
where regexp_like(str, chr(11),'i'); -- case insensitivity doesn't matter unless you're using letters
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using `asciistr()` function within

`regexp_like(clob_, asciistr(chr(to_number('0B','xx'))))` to detect whether exists at least one `vertical tab character` ( Decimal : `11`, Hexadecimal : `0B`  Char : `^K` ) in the `clob_` column

```
select id
  from tab
 where regexp_like(clob_, asciistr(chr(to_number('0B','xx'))))
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=47406fa56638208061dba79c56716747)</kbd>